# How can I add authors in WordPress and assign them a picture?

Tags: users

I know that Wordpress allows us to create a new user and the user's avatar is got from Gravatar service base on their email. How can I add authors in WordPress and assign them a picture (without using Gravatar service ) ?

Thank you !

P/S: I am sorry for my bad English. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a bunch of plugins that adds this functionality to wordpress, this one seems pretty neat, [User Avatar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-avatar/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a plugin for that, for example: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-photo/

Comment: Thank for your quick feedback. I found the plugin which helped me solve this problem. Again, thanks so much.